# External SWF Loading problem

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I have an SWF loading in an SWF containing a papervision scene.

I've done it before yet problem is, I get an error - I'm not sure what the issue really is.

```
    private function downloadSWF(url:String):void
  {
   trace(url);
   var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
   var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
   loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loaderProgressEventHandler);
   loader.load(urlRequest);
  }



 private function loaderProgressEventHandler(ev:ProgressEvent):void
  {

   loader.preloaderCircle.percent = ev.bytesLoaded / ev.bytesTotal;
  }
```

When the application runs the code - I get the error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at com.dehash.pv3d.examples.physics::WowDemo()
```

Why am I getting this if the loading hasn't even complete yet?

Thanks in advance guys.

---

**Edit:** *Try a blank child swf, see if the other one was trying access something in the parent. – Jorge*

I did this, it seems, even with a simple SWF with a mouse click listener causes the Error:

`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at simple_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()`

My code for that is:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

function onClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("MouseClick");
}
```

Am I missing something blatantly obvious??

Comment: If loader is a Loader Object(var loader:Loader = new Loader()), then where does preloaderCircle come from ?(loader.preloaderCircle.percent), unless var loader:Loader is local variable  in downloadSWF, and loader in loaderProgressEventHandler is a reference to a preloader MovieClip. Also check if the demo is trying to access the stage in any way. If it does, preload your swf, add it to stage and on the ADDED_TO_STAGE event handler use an init() method or something to run your loaded swf.

Comment: Thanks George. Your right `loader.preloaderCircle...` should be `loaderMenu.preloaderCircle`, naffy typo from me. And the init() method is a perfect idea. Nice one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the loaded swf starts running without it being added to the stage. So `stage` is null, resulting in that error.

The second example with the addedToStageEventHandler works because there `stage` is only referenced after the object was added to the stage, so `stage` is not null anymore.

A possible solution for the first error is adding the loader to the stage. That way, when the swf is loaded and starts, it already has a `stage` reference.

Comment: Thank you dude. Makes so much sense now.

Answer (score 1):

It won't even load if there's an error. You're accessing an unreferenced object on the WowDemo() class...did you instantiate correctly the class?

Comment: Aye, I think so - The SWF I'm loading runs fine on its own. The parent SWF runs ok too, just when I try to load the child SWF, thats when this error pops up. Is it possible the child SWF is trying to use a library from the parent?

Comment: As an additional, it all works when I don't try and load an external SWF with papervision.

Comment: Try a blank child swf, see if the other one was trying access something in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work inside my child SWF:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageEventHandler);

function onClick(ev:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("MouseClick");
    var event:Event = new Event("END", true, false);
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function addedToStageEventHandler(ev:Event):void
{
    this.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

}
```

does anyone know Why?